# iPhone Tabbar Application: Is it possible to add subview inside the tabbar (on top of it)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, addsubview

i'm working on a uitabbar application and im wondering if its possible to put a view inside it.

my main purpose for this is i 2ill put a semi-transparent music player with about 20 pixels above the tabbar so when the user switches between other views the music play wont stop.

You can see a similar solution in Madonna App (whis is made with Mobile Roadie).

Thanks for helping again. hope someones knows this

Comment: well i guess its not possible :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put views "on top of" your entire application by putting them as subviews of the app's window.   For example, this will "float" a red rectangle over your entire app (I tried it out in a tab-bar based app and it worked great):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIView *myView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 50, 50, 50, 50 )] autorelease];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.window addSubview:myView];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, also i solved this with a different approach: i inserted new layers (CGLayer) over the main view layer within the app delegate of my tabbar application.